# I am updating Angular version from 7 to 8. But getting peer dependency error

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8, npm-update

I tried using --force , but of no use.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN5Lh.jpg)

error code -

```
    Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to   "@angular/common" (requires "^7.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.9").
 Package "@swimlane/ngx-charts" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/animations" (requires "6.x" (extended), would install "9.1.9").
                  Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires ">=2.3.1 <8.0.0 || >7.0.0-beta <8.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.9").
                  Package "@swimlane/ngx-charts" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "6.x" (extended), would install "9.1.9").
                  Package "@swimlane/ngx-charts" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" (requires "^6.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.9").
                  Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/forms" (requires "^7.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.9").
                  Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=2.3.1 <8.0.0 || >7.0.0-beta <8.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.9").
                  Package "ngx-jsoneditor" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "^5.1.0", would install "6.5.5").
                  Package "ngx-jsoneditor" has an incompatible peer dependency to "zone.js" (requires "^0.8.4", would install "0.10.3").
```

Comment: Please note that a [mre] **as text** must be in the question itself. Screenshots are not acceptable. *Pictures of screens* even less so.

Comment: Tip: use powershell or VS Code's terminal. It will allow you to easily copy text.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the compatible version of each dependency here's the code for that

```
npm i --save dependencyName@version
```

Comment: Can you post some example from above error... I am new to angular @Ess

Comment: if you already have your dependency installed then use this `ng update swimlane/ngx-charts@~8.2.12` otherwise do it this way `npm i swimlane/ngx-charts@^8.2.12 --save`. If you need more details check this: [checkMe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55639190/upgrading-ngx-bootstrap-3-0-1-to-4-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

try adding `force flag`

```
ng update @angular/core --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to below command hopefully, it will be fixed

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

Comment: I tired...but same issue @Dev216

Comment: Try to ng update --all --force

Comment: If It does not work then you run below command ----         ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --force

Comment: npm i @angular/cdk@8 @angular/compiler-cli@8 @angular/material@8 rxjs@8 --save

Comment: @Owais Now your issue has solved?